# Using APEX_DATA_EXPORT to store PDF files in DB

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to figure out how to use `APEX_DATA_EXPORT` API to store PDF file in database table. I created a table with one column as a blob.

Has anyone tried to use `APEX_DATA_EXPORT`  to store data in database?

```sql
DECLARE
    l_context apex_exec.t_context; 
    l_export  apex_data_export.t_export;
BEGIN
    apex_session.create_session (
    p_app_id   => 130408,
    p_page_id  => 1,
    p_username => 'EXAMPLE USER' );

    l_context := apex_exec.open_query_context(
        p_location    => apex_exec.c_location_local_db,
        p_sql_query   => 'select * from emp' );

    l_export := apex_data_export.export (
        p_context   => l_context,
        p_format    => nvl(:format, apex_data_export.c_format_pdf),
        p_file_name => 'employees' );

    apex_exec.close( l_context );

    apex_data_export.download(
        p_export => l_export,
        --p_content_disposition => apex_data_export.c_inline,
        p_stop_apex_engine => false);

insert into pdf_test4 (pdf) values l_export;

EXCEPTION
    when others THEN
        apex_exec.close( l_context );
        raise;
END;
```

Comment: Anyone?  I would appreciate any advice

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working for Excel so I guess it would work the same for pdf (change p_format)

```
DECLARE
   v_sql  varchar2(32000) := 'select * from my_data_table';
   v_sql_trimmed varchar2(32000);
  
    l_query_output   CLOB;
 p_file_id number;
 l_file_name varchar2(200) := 'My File - '||sysdate;
 p_status varchar2(100);
 p_tag_id number;

    l_context apex_exec.t_context; 
    l_export  apex_data_export.t_export;
BEGIN
begin
    
    l_context := apex_exec.open_query_context(
        p_location    => apex_exec.c_location_local_db,
        p_sql_query   => v_sql );

    l_export := apex_data_export.export (
        p_context   => l_context,
        p_format    => apex_data_export.c_format_xlsx,
        p_file_name => l_file_name );

    apex_exec.close( l_context );


insert into my_files_table columns (file_blob,filename,file_mimetype,TAG,LOG,TAG_ID) values (l_export.content_blob , l_export.file_name,l_export.mime_type,'Latest','Y',1);
EXCEPTION
    when others THEN
        apex_exec.close( l_context );
        raise;
END;
end;
```